# V is a linear space of n dimensions, show that V has subspaces of every dimension between 0 and n.

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I need to be using induction in this case. i prove the subspace with dimension 0, then assume there is a subspace of k dimensions and then prove that k+1 holds under addition/scalar multiplication aswell.

any hints/advice?

Comment: $V$ has a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$. Define $U_i=span\{e_1,\ldots,e_i\}$. Then $\dim U_i=i$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  Please don't answer in the comment section.

Comment: I didn't know it was a duplicate. And if you knew it was, why give a hint? Regarding answers in the comment section, you are definitely not the only one, if it is any consolation to you;  it is a huge problem with this site, that leaves thousands of questions unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything that complicated. You will obtain a subspace of dimension $k$ if you take the span of $k$ linearly independent vectors.

So, if you fix a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, you can form subspaces 
$$
V_k=\text{span}\,\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}
$$
and you will have $\dim V_k=k$.